# Apache setting custom headers with mod_header, but when enabling mod_cache, wrong headers can be sent to wrong people

Tags: apache-http-server, http

I like to put custom headers in my Apache server's HTTP responses (using `mod_header`) based on whether the request came in over IPV4 or IPV6, like this:

```
<If "%{IPV6} == 'on'">
  Header always setifempty notice "you are using IPV6, keep up the good work"
</If>
<Else>
  <If "%{IPV6} == 'off'">
    Header always setifempty notice "expr=it's %{TIME_YEAR} and you're still using IPV4, (snarky comment redacted)"
  </If>
  <Else>
    Header always setifempty notice "????how did you do that????"
  </Else>
</Else>
```

This was working great until I decided to enable `mod_cache`

now it's caching my custom headers which can result in unwanted behavior like the IPV4 header being delivered to an IPV6 visitor, or vice versa.  For example, an IPV4 request is received, response is cached, then an IPV6 request is received, and the response is served from cache, but it doesn't re-check the custom header logic

I'd like to leave `mod_cache` enabled but only if I can find a way to make it co-exist peacefully with my custom headers.

My `mod_cache` configuration:

```
CacheSocache "shmcb:cache(2147483648)"
CacheEnable socache /
```

running Apache/2.4.52

Update, I've also added `CacheQuickHandler off` as I think that's going to to be necessary although on its own it didn't get the job done.  I think the filter chain order might need tweaking but I'm not really understanding how.

Comment: I've been reading up on Vary headers but I think I've reached a roadblock.  I thought maybe I could set a "Vary:" referencing my custom response header, but I think "Vary:" can only reference headers from the original request.  And my server's decision on how to set the custom header isn't based on a particular request header, it's based on visitor IP.

Comment: FYI: there are still a lot of IPv6 -> IPv4 translation in the world. I would not implement a detector for IPv4 unless this was necessary for an internal application or corporate policy. If you do not want clients to connect using IPv4, do not publish a DNS A resource record. Since you are, that means you support IPv4. If you are actually doing something else, then update your post to show what you are actually doing.

Comment: I don't mind them connecting (for now), I just want to provide them a bit of gentle admonishment which they'll probably never see because most people don't look at HTTP headers.   It's more personal catharsis than anything else.

Comment: I would not do that. Unusual headers can get your response blocked by security systems. Your opinion of IPv4 versus IPv6 should be private. Nobody will listen anyways. If you did that, I would add your site to a block list. In the real world, the cost to implement IPv6 is not practical for many customers. In other cases, IPv6 is proxied to IPv4, which is very common for mobile devices. You would only get a negative reputation.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but the code has already been in place and functional for over a year, and accuracy issues were only encountered when mod_cache was enabled.  If it turns out there's no way to make this compatible with mod_cache then I'll just disable mod_cache since I care more about the headers than I do about the caching but I still believe there may be a way to resolve the incompatibility.  It's not a commercial website so hypothetical blacklisting costs me nothing.

Comment: I think this line has (a part of) the reason why mod_cache is not working: [If, for example, your configuration permits access to a resource by IP address you should ensure that this content is not cached. You can do this by using the CacheDisable directive, or mod_expires. Left unchecked, mod_cache - very much like a reverse proxy - would cache the content when served and then serve it to any client, on any IP address.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html#:~:text=If%2C%20for%20example,any%20IP%20address.).  Or, in short, mod_cache does not look at ip-addresses when caching

Comment: Seems like I might need to add a request header and then Vary on that.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

How I ended up solving this:

first, Cache Quick Handler had to be turned off

```
CacheQuickHandler off
```

this moves caching from the start of the filter chain to the end

second, we need the cache module (which only cares about request headers) to distinguish between IPV4 and IPV6 connections, so we have Apache add a request header for this purpose:

```
<If "%{IPV6} == 'on'">
  RequestHeader set is-ipv6 "YES"
  Header always setifempty notice "(message redacted)"
</If>
<Else>
  <If "%{IPV6} == 'off'">
    RequestHeader set is-ipv6 "NO"
    Header always setifempty notice "(message redacted)"
  </If>
  <Else>
    RequestHeader set is-ipv6 "WTF"
    Header always setifempty notice "(message redacted)"
  </Else>
</Else>
```

Third, we need to tell the proxy module that requests with different `is-ipv6` headers should be cached seperately

I already had a Vary header set like this:

```
Header append Vary Accept-Encoding env=!dont-vary
```

so I changed it to this:

```
Header append Vary "Accept-Encoding, is-ipv6" env=!dont-vary
```

this resolves all known issues

note this will lower cache performance somewhat, due to otherwise-idental IPV4 and IPV6 requests having to be cached separately.